# When are nodal lines on a sphere geodesics?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, elliptic-pde, schrodinger-operators, closed-geodesic

Let $(S^2, g)$ be a Riemannian sphere and let $L := \Delta_{S^2} + q$ be a Schrödinger operator on $S^2$. Suppose that $L$ has index equal to one and that $u \in C^{\infty}(S^2)$ ($u \neq 0$) lies in the kernel of $L$. Since $u$ changes sign, it has exactly $2$ nodal domains, and Theorem 2.5 by Shiu-Yuen Cheng in ["Eigenfunctions and Nodal Sets"](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN358147735_0051?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B53%5D,%22panX%22:0.403,%22panY%22:0.797,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.346%7D) shows that the nodal set $$C = \{ x \in S^2 : u(x) = 0 \}$$ must be a $C^2$ immersed circle. Can we expect that $C$ is in fact a closed **geodesic** of $(S^2,g)$?